# If I set auto_id=true, then I insert data into milvus concurrently. Will the id in Milvus be repeated?

Tags: vector, insert, milvus

If I set auto_id=true, then I insert data into milvus concurrently.  Will the id in Milvus be repeated?

I am using Milvus2.0.

Answer (score 1):

All returned IDs are unique, for my understanding, internally all data are inserted in sequence.

Here is an official Q&A for this question: https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/discussions/3860